# Add Controls to GroupBox which was created dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol, groupbox

I add GroupBoxes to an ItemsControl dynamically using:

```
string name_ = "TestName", header_ = "TestHeader"
GroupBox MyGroupBox = new GroupBox { Name = name_, Header= header_, Width = 240, Height = 150, Foreground=new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0)) };

MyItemsControl.Items.Add(MyGroupBox);
```

Now I need to add content to this GroupBox, like a few TextBlocks created like:

```
TextBlock MyTextBlock = new TextBlock {Text = "test"};
```

But I can't figure out how to do that. Normally to a Grid or something like that I would just use .Children.Add(MyTextBlock), but that doesn't work here.

Also I have to be able to remove specific Items from the ItemsControl again (best would be by the name of the Item, name_ in this example).

Comment: See if anything in this [MSDN Search](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/search/en-us?query=find+controls+by+name+in+wpf&x=0&y=0) Helps as far as finding your Controls, once you found them you can use `myItemsControl.Items.Remove(object)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like that

```
GroupBox groupBox1 = new GroupBox();
Grid grid1 = new Grid();
TextBlock MyTextBlock = new TextBlock {Text = "test"};
groupBox1.Width = 185;
groupBox1.Height = 160;
grid1.Height =  185;
grid1.Width =  160;
grid1.Children.Add(MyTextBlock);
groupBox1.Content = grid1;
mainWindow.canvas.Children.Add(groupBox1);
```

Comment: Any idea how to remove items from the ItemsControl by the name?

Comment: I am new to WPF, it is a silly question but I need to know, in th above answer what is mainwindow.canvas. while I place the above code in my page it is showing error in the mainwindow.canvas. what is mainwindow object in the above answer. 1) I need to create any canvas in the xaml(design) page?

Comment: Yea what is the data type of mainWindow? There is no property canvas of mainWindow

Answer (score 0):

The GroupBox has only a [Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx) Property which is designed to hold a ContentPresentor. You can add a Grid/Canvas etc.. to the GroupBox and then add your content to that.